# Labview control panel moving objects inside tab according to window size (not the tab)

Tags: user-interface, labview

My Labview control panel is moving objects inside a tab according to window size (not the tab). Please note that this is happening in a huge project. I made a new one just to illustrate the problem, but in this case I had to move the object by myself.

Sample:

Look the position of the numeric control and the window size.
[image]
Now after the window is resized the control is moved.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Labview bug!

File / VI Properties / Window Size
Select/Deselect "Scale all objects on front panel as the window resizes*"
Ok

Done!

Comment: What is your LabView version, I can't reproduce the problem with LV2012

Comment: 2015, this was some kind of bug, I don't know how to reproduce it, only how to solve it.